# Dynamic variable value from php and mysql to work in html Body tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php tag where I try too retrieve from the database to get some values.
Followed by declaring those values to a variable, then make use of those variable to pass value to a html body tag.

PHP:

```
 <?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM productItem;";
            // Write a statement to open a connection to MySQL server
            $link = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "6i7yvBku");
            // Write a statement to select the required database
            mysql_select_db("KXCLUSIVE", $link);
            // Write a statement to send the SQL statement to the MySQL server for execution and retrieve the resultset
            $resultset = mysql_query($sql);
            // Write a statement to close the connection
            mysql_close($link);

 $year = $row["year"];
 $month = $row["month"];
 ?>
```

HTML:

```
 <body onload="countdown(year,month)">
```

How should I go about putting the php variable ($year and $month) into the html body tag (to replace the year and month variable in the body tag??

Comment: php and html both are in separate files ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="<?php echo "countdown($year,$month)" ; ?>">
```

this should do.. and for future refrence don't use mysql_ they are depreciated use mysqli/PDO http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php